# How can I separate people per groups on Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 groups of people "A" and "B"

[image: groups of people]

both groups work on the same tasks

[image: tasks assigned to people]

but I would like to get them with an "@" on a different sheet; separated into groups (group A and B) and both groups mixed (general)

[image: People per group and general result]

Does anyone know how can I automatically separate them into groups A and B? I was wondering if I could use a match formula and an if formula, I tried to do it but had no success. The task can vary but no the group so the best would be to get formula or any way to automatically add thee people per group.

As an additional info I used this formula to get the general result: =IFNA(CONCATENATE("@"; TEXTJOIN(" @"; TRUE ;QUERY('Sheet 1'!A3:E12 ;"select A where B = TRUE";0));""))

This is the Google sheet I've been using to try to do this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fdQJcIuqFTfo8upNOtALk0vhQYjSM0d8nYRML4amuM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In Excel you could use a combination of FILTER and DROP/COUNTA to get the first and second half of the group separated. Not sure how it works in Sheets. Or INDEX COUNTA/2.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @TheMaster I appreciate it I'll consider it the next time and I'm also reading the table you sent. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the opposing group in general category using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

For group A, replace B:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B3:B6,"@"&JOIN("( |$)|@",FILTER(Sheet3!A3:A12,Sheet3!C3:C12)),))
```

where `B3:B6` is the General category's values column and `Sheet3` contains Groups.

This creates a regex like

```
@P1( |$)|@P2( |$)|@P5( |$)|@P6( |$)|@P8( |$)|@P10
```

Which is `@` followed by any group `P1` and followed by a space or end of string`( |$)`. For this to work properly, avoid regex meta characters in People names.

Comment: thank you so much for your response! it works! but unfortunately, I was confused, in the "general" there is no "@" and I can see that if I remove the @ it also disappears from the A and B groups. Is there any way to add the "@ just in the groups?

Comment: @ElmarOnassis I don't get it. This formula doesn't touch "General".  It depends on `@` in the general. Isn't that what your formula does: `IFNA(CONCATENATE("@"; TEXTJOIN(" @"; TRUE ;QUERY('Sheet 1'!A3:E12 ;"select A where B = TRUE";0));""))`?

Comment: the formula I used in the general was:

=IFNA(JOIN(", ";QUERY('Sheet 1'!A3:E12 ;"select A where B = TRUE";0));"")

Sorry for the misunderstood.
When I use the correct formula in the "General" on "Sheet 2" it seems the formula you have provided me doesn't work properly.

I also edited the post and the Google sheets

Could you help me with this?

Comment: @ElmarOnassis Changing the question after receiving answers is frowned upon. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

B10:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(B3:B6; "@ "); 
 IF('Sheet 3'!B3:B12; 'Sheet 3'!A3:A12; ); "@"&'Sheet 3'!A3:A12;;; 1));;9^9))))
```

[image]

B17:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(B3:B6; "@ "); 
 IF('Sheet 3'!C3:C12; 'Sheet 3'!A3:A12; ); "@"&'Sheet 3'!A3:A12;;; 1));;9^9))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Paste this formulas**
in `Sheet2` cells `A3` , `A10` , `A17` and make sure to apply it in your shared [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14fdQJcIuqFTfo8upNOtALk0vhQYjSM0d8nYRML4amuM/edit?usp=sharing)  and with the same [locale](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) in your case [spain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVcUe.jpg)

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
                              { 'Sheet 1'!B2:E2;
                                BYCOL(IF('Sheet 1'!B3:E<>TRUE;;
                                      LAMBDA(r; IF(r="";;"@"&r))('Sheet 1'!A3:A));
                                LAMBDA(j; TEXTJOIN(" ";1;j))) }); 
              " Select * Where Col2 <> '' "); ""))
```

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
                              { 'Sheet 1'!B2:E2;
                                BYCOL(IF(IF('Sheet 3'!B3:B<> TRUE; "" ;'Sheet 1'!B3:E )<>TRUE;;
                                      LAMBDA(r; IF(r="";;"@"&r))('Sheet 1'!A3:A));
                                LAMBDA(j; TEXTJOIN(" ";1;j))) }); 
              " Select * Where Col2 <> '' ");""))
```

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
                              { 'Sheet 1'!B2:E2;
                                BYCOL(IF(IF('Sheet 3'!C3:C<> TRUE; "" ;'Sheet 1'!B3:E )<>TRUE;;
                                      LAMBDA(r; IF(r="";;"@"&r))('Sheet 1'!A3:A));
                                LAMBDA(j; TEXTJOIN(" ";1;j))) }); 
              " Select * Where Col2 <> '' ");""))
```

[image]

### Demo

[image]

Functions used
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`TRANSPOSE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`BYCOL`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

Comment: Hey, @Osm it works perfectly! but when I unmark a checkbox on "Sheet 1" it comes with a #Value! error instead of getting the cell blank. Is there a way to get the cells blank instead of this error?

Comment: @ElmarOnassis the answer is updated empty checkboxes are handled now

Comment: Hey @Osm, actually I had some problems putting the formula in the real sheet, I tried to get just the "@Ps" without the titles "Group A" or "Task3" etc. But no success.

Another problem I had is that I have some columns that I would like to avoid, for instance, get results for the "New task" Old task" avoid "task 3" but include "Task4".

Is there any way to do this?

Sorry for bothering you again!
Thank you so much for your help!